# Why is intelliJ not using the correct version of .xsd file

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, xsd

Here is my spring-security.xml file

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
```

So the last line specifies a 3.0 version, which is a valid xsd file if you go to the URL it will show schema. If I COMMAND + B on that xsd it takes me to a 2.0 version.

I know a 3.0.8 spring-security xsd file exists on my computer, intelliJ just won't use it (even though it downloaded it!).

How do I manually place this xsd file in my project?

Comment: Perhaps you have an older version of Spring Security in your classpath? Use Ctrl + mouseover on the URL and IntelliJ will show you where it finds the XSD in your filesystem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA validates toward wrong XSD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913810/intellij-idea-validates-toward-wrong-xsd)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i resolved it by removing the spring-dao jar from the application. Below link will provide more details to you :
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4161

Answer (score 0):

Removing sping-dao jar file worked for me.
Added below in spring-aop dependency.

```
<exclusion> 
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```