# NoSuchMethodError: registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary with Spring 4, Hibernate 4 and Maven 3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I tried to configure Hibernate and Spring but I can't resolve this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary`.

I tried some solutions without success. I need you're help!

I followed this tutorial: http://websystique.com/spring/spring4-hibernate4-mysql-maven-integration-example-using-annotations/

Here is some information:

**Stacktrace**

```
Nov 23, 2014 6:16:55 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@13f17c9e: startup date [Sun Nov 23 18:16:55 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 23, 2014 6:16:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-config.xml]
Nov 23, 2014 6:16:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [hibernate-config.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:hibernate-config.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [hibernate-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:235)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [hibernate-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:229)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 30 more
```

**spring-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <import resource="classpath:hibernate-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

**hibernate-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3</groupId>
    <artifactId>equipe07-log720-A14-lab3</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>equipe07-log720-A14-lab3 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>equipe07-log720-A14-lab3</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**mvn dependency:tree**

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ equipe07-log720-A14-lab3 ---
[INFO] ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3:equipe07-log720-A14-lab3:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.7.Final:compile
```

I'm trying to run this:

**AppMain.java**

```
package ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3;

import ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3.model.Dossier;
import ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3.service.DossierService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.List;

public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

        DossierService service = (DossierService) context.getBean("dossierService");

        /*
         * Get all employees list from database
         */
        List<Dossier> dossiers = service.findAll();
        for (Dossier dossier : dossiers) {
            System.out.println(dossier);
        }
    }
}
```

If some more code is needed, just ask!

Comment: The stack trace points line 54 of `org.springframework.transaction.config. AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser`, but the source code for Spring 4.1.2 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/config/AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java) says that there's no executable code at that line. That suggests to me that your server is picking up an old version of Spring somehow. Check the WAR file and make sure there's nothing in there that shouldn't be.

Comment: I run `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="ca.etsmtl.log720.lab3.AppMain"` in my Terminal and it worked. So it is my IntelliJ that is not well configured. I set it up with Maven but it is using some other configuration... Thank you, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue with this issue: [Why is intelliJ not using the correct version of .xsd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794728/why-is-intellij-not-using-the-correct-version-of-xsd-file)

My spring-context-4.1.xsd file was using a .jar in my jre/lib from my Java installation.